# C++ Strings In Class Becoming Empty after Construction

Tags: c++, string, class, switch-statement, binary-tree

I'm creating a program where part of its job is to store class objects labeled Client() in a binary tree. 
I create the object within a switch statement with

```
Client newClient = Client (first, last, iD);
transactionsTree.Insert(newClient);
```

The switch statement is in a loop that is reading data, so after this case is executed and the program continues, the strings within that class get set to empty "" strings. I found this out in stepping through debugging and as soon as that case block executes the strings change to empty. Any other data that gets put into that class remains but those strings will not. Even if I declare those string names in the Client.h file they are still empty after the switch case where it was created. The code where I create the newClient shown above is in a Transactions.cpp, the transactionsTree is a class object of BSTree.cpp, and there's also Client.cpp, all these classes share a connection but I'm assuming my problem has to do with how I'm inserting the objects into the binary tree.

Here is the code with the switch statement case:

```
case 'O': // open an account
            {
                string first = list.front();
                list.pop();
                string last = list.front();
                list.pop();
                stringstream getiD(list.front()); // transfer string to int
                list.pop();
                int iD = 0;
                getiD >> iD; // transferring string to int

                if (transactionsTree.Retrieve(iD)) // if Client is already in tree, prints error message
                {
                    cout << "ERROR: Account " << iD << " is already open. Transaction refused." << endl;
                }
                else // else creates new Client
                {
                    Client newClient = Client (first, last, iD);
                    transactionsTree.Insert(newClient);
                }

                break;
            }
```

And here is my insert method for the binary tree:

```
void BSTree::Insert(Client &newClient)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        Node *newNode = new Node(newClient);
        this->root = newNode;
    }
    else
        add(this->root, newClient);
}

BSTree::Node* BSTree::add(Node *node, Client &newClient) // helper function for Insert()
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node(newClient);
            return newNode;
        }
    if (newClient.clientID < node->pClient->clientID)
        node->left = add(node->left, newClient);
    else
        node->right = add(node->right, newClient);
}
```

edit1: Upon further examination, none of the strings in the class that are declared in the header or constructor hold, although here are string vectors that hold. I also have an array of strings with the whole array declared in the header of Client.cpp but when I try and print out any strings from any Client object it only prints out an address.

edit2: I've isolated my problem to two areas, one where I try to access the Client within the tree using:

```
Client *ptrClient; // create pointer to access the Client once found
                        ptrClient = &transactionsTree.getClient(iD);
```

and two within my getClient method which is within my binary tree class:

```
Client& BSTree::getClient(int id) // returns a Client object from the tree to process() in Transactions.cpp
{
    return getTheClient(this->root, id);
}

Client& BSTree::getTheClient(Node * node, int iD) // helper function for getClient that returns a Client object in the tree
{
// no need for the if condition of iD not being found because I check if the iD is in the tree before this function is executed
    if (node->pClient->clientID == iD)
    {
        cout << node->pClient->firstName << " PRINTED HERE~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
        return *node->pClient; // return client if found
    }
    if (iD < node->pClient->clientID)
        return getTheClient(node->left, iD);
    else
        return getTheClient(node->right, iD);
}
```

Does this updated information help you help me solve my problem?

Comment: is `new Node(newClient);` making a copy of `newClient` ? of not you're in for a rough time. `newClient` is a reference to an automatic variable with narrow scope.

Comment: I'm thinking we'll need a [mcve] to give you a 100% correct answer that's useful to other programmers in the future.

Comment: `{ Client newClient = Client (first, last, iD); transactionsTree.Insert(newClient); }` -- This definitely could be an issue, as `newClient` is a temporary.

Comment: Does `Client` have valid copy constructor and assignment operators?

Comment: Not all codepaths of `BSTree::add` return a value

Comment: @MooingDuck No it doesn't have either, I didn't think it would need to why is that a problem?

Comment: @user4581301 How come it isn't being stored within my binary tree class then? ```new Node(newClient)``` is calling my Node constructor ```Node(Client & newClient) : pClient(&newClient)
        {}``` in my binary tree class

Comment: @MooingDuck I see that Not all codepaths of BSTree::add return a value every time I run my program, what does that mean?

Comment: @TroubledProgrammer -- *I see that Not all codepaths of BSTree::add return a value every time I run my program, what does that mean?* -- Your function is supposed to return a `BSTree` pointer.  Do you do that in all the paths the function can take?  You don't.  Thus the behavior of the program is undefined after the `if` statement.  The framework of a tail-recursive function that is supposed to return a value is something like `T foo(some_param) { ( if (whatever) { return a T; }  { return foo(some_params); }` -- Note the `return` at the end.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added return in front of the ```node->left``` and ```node->right``` , my problem still exists

Comment: What we need to see is [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we know how `Client` is defined and how `Node` is defined, and how they are constructed, etc... That will help determine the application of [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (or five or none).

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica I don't really have time to create an entire new smaller version of my program because my assignment is due in 5 hours along with some other things but I've isolated my issue to two areas and I'll update my question

Comment: I understand, but understand in order to help you, especially when dealing with classes implementing a BST storing nodes that we cannot verify how they are defined or constructed makes if very difficult, if not impossible, to pick out the reason your code isn't working from just a few code fragments. Sometimes if the error is obvious that can be done, but other times if the problem depends on some of the code not shown, it results in guess being the best we can do. A MCVE also allows us to compile the code in question and enlist the aid of the compiler in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, it was with the two lines:

```
Client newClient = Client (first, last, iD);
transactionsTree.Insert(newClient);
```

I changed it to:

```
Client *newClient = new Client (first, last, iD);
transactionsTree.Insert(*newClient);
```

This mattered because I was creating a new object in the stack and not the heap.

Comment: This probably does solve the problem, but the way you've done it is goinfg to confuse the hell out of people. Most people seeing the solution will think, "DUDE! why are you leaking that memory?" Consider replacing `void BSTree::Insert(Client &newClient)` with `void BSTree::Insert(Client * newClient)` and make it obvious you're passing a raw pointer throughout. Better still, look into `std::unique_ptr` to make the ownership of the object super obvious..

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks I'll probably make that adjustment before I turn it in, could you help me with another problem? I know whats wrong but I can't figure out why. My binary tree is just overwriting the leaves of the root. This is the function where it's happening

Comment: @user4581301```BSTree::Node* BSTree::add(Node *node, Client &newClient) // helper function for Insert()
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node(newClient);
            node = newNode;
            return newNode;
        }
    if (newClient.clientID < node->pClient->clientID)
        return node->left = add(node->left, newClient);
    else
        return node->right = add(node->right, newClient);
}```